# Troubles Sending Message in IRC using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, irc, twitch, twitch-api

I am trying to create an irc bot using python, but I'm getting an error. When I try to check for a message sent, the PRIVMSG doesn't send a message to the chat, but the test print statement outputs. If I just try to send a message when anything is received it sends the message. I commented in the code where this happens. This is my first time trying to do this, so sorry if I'm a bit inexperienced using python sockets.

```
#connect.py
#connects to twitch irc and presents a class to b

import cfg
import socket
import time

def ban(sock, user):
    chat(sock, ".ban {}".format(user))

def timeout(sock, user, secs=600):
    chat(sock, ".timeout {}".format(user, secs))

# network functions go here

s = socket.socket()
s.connect((cfg.HOST, cfg.PORT))
s.send("PASS {}\r\n".format(cfg.PASS).encode("utf-8"))
s.send("NICK {}\r\n".format(cfg.NICK).encode("utf-8"))
s.send("JOIN {}\r\n".format(cfg.CHAN).encode("utf-8"))

while True:
    time.sleep(0.1)
    response = s.recv(1024).decode("utf-8")
    print(response)
    if response == "PING :tmi.twitch.tv\r\n":
        s.send("PONG :tmi.twitch.tv\r\n".encode("utf-8"))
    elif "hi" in response:
        #prints Condition Worked but doesn't send message
        print("Condition Worked")
        s.send(("PRIVMSG #garrett_the_savage :hello"+"\r\n").encode('utf-8'))
    else
        #sends a message when anything is received from the socket
        s.send(("PRIVMSG #garrett_the_savage :hello"+"\r\n").encode('utf-8'))
```

EDIT: I have a separate file called cfg.py that houses some variables for connecting.

Comment: No message should work for you in Twitch, because they are using `CAP` IRC v3 protocol. read this answer to understand more, and add the `CAP` messages in your code https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51484971/java-twitch-irc-bot

Comment: I understand your trying to help, but I think sending something that was in python would have been far more of a help then something in java...